# Variable declaration using short circuiting

Tags: javascript, jquery

I was just going through a JQuery plugin and came across the following line of code:

```
var doAnimate = $.support.transition && animate
```

I do understand short circuiting, but is that a variable declaration using short circuiting ??

On asking somebody more experienced then me, I got the following reply:

> If they loaded the transition library, use it, otherwise use animate.

I guess  the value returned is not true or false , because i've heard short circuiting does't return true or false .

So if `$.support.transition` is undefined, animate gets stored in `doAnimate`?

Is that how it works? I am really confused about this variable declaration and how it works. I do understand short circuiting in conditionals .

Comment: this code says to me in plain english "if it doesn't support animate and transitions, then don't animate."

Comment: Hi, please kindly look at my small blog about short circuiting and I hope it could help a little: http://js-guru.blogspot.com/2015/08/javascript-short-circuiting.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> "If they loaded the transition library, use it, otherwise use animate."

What they meant was to use `||` operator.

```
var doAnimate = $.support.transition || animate;
```

What the above does is, it checks if `$.support.transition` is available, or loaded, use it, else use `animate`.

When we do `expr1 && expr2`, it returns `expr1` if it is *falsey*; otherwise, returns `expr2`.

So, when you do `var doAnimate = $.support.transition && animate;`, if `$.support.transition` isn't loaded or is `undefined`, `doAnimate` will *still* hold `$.support.transition`, instead of `animate`.

If it is loaded, then `animate` will be used. This is contrary to what you want. That's where `||` comes into action.

When we do `expr1 || expr2` it returns `expr1` if it is *truthy*; otherwise, returns `expr2`.

So when we use `||` and if `$.support.transition` is loaded, it will be used, else `animate` will be used.

[**More on logical operators on MDN**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_Operators)

Comment: `var useThis = ifTruthy || elseThis;`  , can u give me the same syntax for && ? Thanks .

Comment: ur `What the above does is, it checks if $.support.transition is available, or loaded, use it, else use animate.` is the same as `If they loaded the transition library, use it, otherwise use animate.`

Comment: @AlexanderSolonik yes. That's what I was trying to say.

Comment: still does't make sense to me , can you edit the answer to show me the difference between, `var doAnimate = $.support.transition || animate;` and `var doAnimate = $.support.transition && animate;` , I'll accept your answer , if you do so . thanks .

Comment: @AlexanderSolonik I've tried my best to explain what's the difference between them. Check it now.

Comment: @AmitJoki your assumption about they meaning `||` instead of `&&` is wrong. Check my answer below: http://stackoverflow.com/a/36659283/146513

Answer (score 0):

You can tell that the variable "doAnimate" is indeed used as a boolean, && is what they meant to write. "doAnimate" will be either true or false.

&& is a binary logical operator equivalent to AND. If you're aware of the truth table for && you already know that both elements in the expression need to be true for the whole expression to be evaluated as true.
Short circuiting leverages on this factor: if the first element is false then you don't need to check for the second.
In javascript true\false are handled rather... creatively. In this case undefined is evaluated as false.
You can read more at [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_Operators)

Answer (score 0):

In your case:

```
var doAnimate = $.support.transition && animate;
```

Only if `$.support.transition` truthy it will evaluate `animate` and assign `animate` to `doAnimate`.

If `$.support.transition` is falsy. Then it will return value of `$.support.transition`.

If both the values are truthy then it will take `animate` only.

But what you really want is:

```
var doAnimate = $.support.transition || animate;
```

It checks for truthiness from left to right. If it comes across any first truthy value, it will store that to doAnimate.

Answer (score 0):

The code from the question is part of bootstrap. So it's well tested and clearly not wrong. And other answers saying that the code should have been `||` instead of `&&` are not really understanding the real intention of the code in this case ([Sphaso's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28911980/146513) is right, but I'll try to explain it better).

If we check [Bootstrap sourcecode](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/blob/v3.3.0/js/tests/index.html#L55) we see that `$.support.transition` is a boolean. And I copied below the [relevant portion of that bootstrap code](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/blob/v3.3.0/js/modal.js#L163-L187) in which we can see the rest of the code including the line of code in the question:

```
var animate = this.$element.hasClass('fade') ? 'fade' : ''  // <--- animate is a string
// ... more code ...
  var doAnimate = $.support.transition && animate           // <--- doAnimate is either
                                                            //      a string or false
  this.$backdrop = $('<div class="modal-backdrop ' + animate + '" />') // <- animate used
                                                                       //    as a string
  // ... more code ...
  if (doAnimate) this.$backdrop[0].offsetWidth  // <- doAnimate used only for truthfulness
  // ... more code ...
  doAnimate ?  // <---------------------------------- doAnimate used only for truthfulness
    this.$backdrop
      .one('bsTransitionEnd', callback)
      .emulateTransitionEnd(Modal.BACKDROP_TRANSITION_DURATION) :
    callback()
```

So Bootstrap is doing 3 actions in this code (and that is why they need 2 variables, if only 2 actions were needed they probably would have not created the doAnimate variable in this way and just made the whole thing inline):

- 1 action is using the `animate` variable which has a string used for css classes (set with either `'fade'` or `''`). But the condition to get that variable set is not trivial (the call `hasClass`), so instead of calling that again in later code they decided to reuse this string variable as it were a boolean.
- The other 2 action depend on the `doAnimate` variable, which although it might have diffent types inside, they just use it as a boolean without strict comparisons.

  `doAnimate` might have inside:

  - a string: either `'fade'` (considered `truthy`), or the empty string `''` (considered `falsy`).
  - or a simple boolean (in the case that `$.support.transition` is `false`).

  And as long as you use `doAnimate` just for truthfulness (as in the examples in the code) the code will work just fine. And `doAnimate` will be `truthy` only when `transition` is `truthy` and `animate` is `'fade'` (meaning that `this.$element.hasClass('fade')`).

But be carefull with this kind of optimizations. Most programmers are not used variables having different types in different cases, and will see this code as too complex. So in most situations you might want add another variable to store just the result of `this.$element.hasClass('fade')`, and use that boolean in `doAnimate` (instead of using the `animate` string).